# How can I run cargo check/test individually on each feature of my Cargo.toml?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, conditional-compilation

Cargo features allow [conditional compilation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/conditional-compilation.html#the-cfg_attr-attribute), so the final build will have just specific groups of features which can be filtered by the final user.

Now depending on the complexity of a library crate, you may end with several features forming a dependency tree, something like:

```ini
[features]
banana = []
avocado = []
pineapple = ["avocado"]
orange = ["pineapple", "banana"]
```

It's natural that, beyond `cargo check|test --all-features`, I will want to run `cargo check|test --features banana` on each one of the individual features, to ensure they can live on their own. Currently I'm doing this with a crude shell script, manually fed with the features. If I add a new feature and I forget to add it to the script, I'm in trouble.

```bash
FEATS=(banana avocado pineapple orange)

for FEAT in "${FEATS[@]}" ; do
    echo "$FEAT..."
    cargo check --features "$FEAT"
    #cargo test --features "$FEAT"
done
```

So, is there any automated way to run `cargo check|test --features banana` on each feature, one by one, then report the warnings/errors which have been found?

Comment: Not natively with `cargo`. I guess you'd a script that parses your `Cargo.toml` and collects all the features automatically. I bet you can whip that up in Python in a couple of lines.

Comment: You may want to set up a code coverage report so that you can see what your shell script has and hasn't tested.

Answer (score 4):

I recently found [`taiki-e/cargo-hack`](https://github.com/taiki-e/cargo-hack) which claims to handle this problem. I haven't tried it myself.

> cargo-hack is basically wrapper of cargo that propagates subcommand and most of the passed flags to cargo, but provides additional flags and changes the behavior of some existing flags.
>
> #### `--each-feature`
>
> Perform for each feature which includes default features and `--no-default-features` of the package.
>
> This is useful to check that each feature is working properly.

Answer (score 2):

There is the [cargo-all-features](https://crates.io/crates/cargo-all-features) crate that provides commands for using *all combination of features*, not only individual features:

```
> cargo install cargo-all-features --locked
```

With it installed, you can run the following cargo commands to check, test, and build:

```
> cargo check-all-features
> cargo test-all-features
> cargo build-all-features
```

Further customizations (like skipping features or combinations) can be set by configuring the `[package.metadata.cargo-all-features]` section in your Cargo.toml.